# How can I use Slim micro framework inside Drupal?

Tags: php, apache, routes, drupal-7, slim

Good Morning,
I have a question about using Slim inside Drupal : I have an existing website project made with Drupal inside my apache server. My work was to add another part to the existing website and I decided to work without Drupal but with Slim micro framework (v2). After finishing my website, I created a folder inside the root of the Drupal project folder and I puted my website inside this folder.

[This is how the Drupal folder looks with the new folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkHIa.png).
(folders may be scripts, misc,... and files may be .htaccess, index.php,...)

After that I try to access to my website with this URL : http://www.thewebsite.com/MYNEWFOLDER/ and it redirect me to the route "/" that I have added inside my route.php file : everything is normal.

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app){
MYCODE});
```

Then I try http://www.thewebsite.com/MYNEWFOLDER/admin because there is a route "/admin" that I have also added inside my route.php file but instead of accessing to this part of the website, it redirect me to a drupal error 404 page which says : '"MYNEWFOLDER/admin" not found.'.

```
$app->get('/admin(/)', function (){
MYCODE});
```

My question is :  how can I tell to Drupal this folder MYNEWFOLDER has to be ignored AND how can I access to http://www.thewebsite.com/MYNEWFOLDER/admin without being redirected by Drupal ?

Have a nice day !

(Sorry for my English btw ^^)

Comment: Did you test your slim instance by itelf to ensure it works 100%, before placing it inside drupal?  e.g. That 404 doesn't really say whether it's slim or drupal that's a problem

Comment: I never use Drupal, but if you use Apache and .htaccess I believe you can create RewriteRule pattern to match MYNEWFOLDER and tells what actual index.php to use. To me however, is to setup slim as different application or if you cant, may be under its own separate sub domain.

Comment: The 404 page is the page where Drupal can't find the route, I mean all the style of the page is the Drupal's style so I'm sure that Drupal is blocking Slim activity.

Comment: I already tried to rewrite rule in .htaccess but it doesn't worked for me ^^.

Comment: @J.Johny Where you able to get this working? I think you could add some rule in Drupal's htaccess to ignore all urls going to sub directory of your slim app and then have a separate htaccess of its own for slim. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 and Slim 3:

Use Form API to create a route using a load argument:
You will need to route Drupal's http request object to Slim

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

function my_modulename_menu() {
   $items['my/page/%my_modulename_somefunction'] = array(
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),

return $items;

}

function my_modulename_somefunction_load($var) {

   $app = new \Slim\App;
   $request = request_path(); // set the Drupal request object here

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "my/page/" . $var) {

      $app->get('/my/page/{passed}', function ($request, $response, array $args) {

      $stuff = $args['passed']

      // do something with your data here

      return $response->withJson($stuff);

    });

    $app->run();
    exit;
  }

}
```

This will output whatever is passed after /my/page/ to the user, independant of Drupals theming layer and restricted to a particular path in Drupal, without clobbering your webserver.

https://github.com/slimphp.

I'm the author of this module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_slim_api

Additional documentation for D7 Form API found here:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x

https://www.drupal.org/node/224170